# WPF databinding to interface and not actual object - casting possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Say I have an interface like this:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
...
}
```

I also have a couple of classes implementing this interface;

```
public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
{
...
}
```

Now I have a WPF ListBox listing items of ISomeInterface, using a custom DataTemplate.

The databinding engine will apparently not (that I have been able to figure out) allow me to bind to interface properties - it sees that the object is a SomeClass object, and data only shows up if SomeClass should happen to have the bound property available as a non-interface property.

How can I tell the DataTemplate to act as if every object is an ISomeInterface, and not a SomeClass etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the notification @slugster, I updated the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In order to bind to explicit implemented interface members, all you need to do is to use the parentheses. For example:

implicit:

```
{Binding Path=MyValue}
```

explicit:

```
{Binding Path=(mynamespacealias:IMyInterface.MyValue)}
```

Comment: Glad I stumbled across this, it also helped me resolve an issue with binding to PostSharp-created objects; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636962/binding-wpf-controls-to-dynamically-introduced-interfaces-on-model-objects

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't actually seem to work for the OP's question (I know this question is very old). He didn't ask about a binding, but `DataType="{x:Type local:SomeClassBase}"`.

Comment: @Steve this answer is correct - the OP is talking about binding paths within the data template, explicit interface properties on the concrete type are not visible to the binding engine by default (implicit ones are). I believe the accepted answer wasn't really what the OP was after, especially as this answer was posted a whole year later.

Comment: This works but unfortunately the engine isn't wise enough to add an handler to a `IMyInterface.MyValueChanged` event, should there be one. This means that if you want changes notifications, the implementing class must also be implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and use the exact same name of the interface property. This could be a problem if multiple interfaces are implemented explicitely and the same property name exists on more than one. Use wisely.

Comment: The `"Path="` is very important. It didn't work until I added that.

Answer (score 21):

[This answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1e774a24-0deb-4acd-a719-32abd847041d/data-templates-and-interfaces) from Microsoft forums by [Beatriz Costa - MSFT](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/beatriz%20costa%20-%20msft/?ws=usercard-inline) is worth reading (rather old):

> The data binding team discussed adding support for interfaces a while ago but ended up not implementing it because we could not come up with a good design for it. The problem was that interfaces don't have a hierarchy like object types do. Consider the scenario where your data source implements both `IMyInterface1` and `IMyInterface2` and you have DataTemplates for both of those interfaces in the resources: which DataTemplate do you think we should pick up?
>
> When doing implicit data templating for object types, we first try to find a `DataTemplate` for the exact type, then for its parent, grandparent and so on. There is very well defined order of types for us to apply. When we talked about adding support for interfaces, we considered using reflection to find out all interfaces and adding them to the end of the list of types. The problem we encountered was defining the order of the interfaces when the type implements multiple interfaces.
>
> The other thing we had to keep in mind is that reflection is not that cheap, and this would decrease our perf a little for this scenario.
>
> So what's the solution? You can't do this all in XAML, but you can do it easily with a little bit of code. The `ItemTemplateSelector` property of `ItemsControl` can be used to pick which `DataTemplate` you want to use for each item. In the `SelectTemplate` method for your template selector, you receive as a parameter the item you will template. Here, you can check for what interface it implements and return the `DataTemplate` that matches it.

Answer (score 14):

The short answer is DataTemplate's do not support interfaces (think about multiple inheritance, explicit v. implicit, etc). The way we tend to get around this is to have a base class things extend to allow the DataTemplate specialization/generalization. This means a decent, but not necessarily optimal, solution would be:

```
public abstract class SomeClassBase
{

}

public class SomeClass : SomeClassBase
{

}

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeClassBase}">
    <!-- ... -->
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll accept your answer even though this means I pretty much have to rework quite a bit of stuff to do what I want. Some times life sucks when you're tasked with putting a WPF UI on top of a library of existing business objects.. :)

Comment: @Rune Jacobsen: We're dealing with the same growing pains at our shop too.

Answer (score 9):

You have another option. Set a Key on your DataTemplate and reference that key in the ItemTemplate. Like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type documents:ISpecificOutcome}"
              x:Key="SpecificOutcomesTemplate">
    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"
           ToolTip="{Binding Description}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

then reference the template by key where you want to use it, like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SpecificOutcomes}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SpecificOutcomesTemplate}"
         >
</ListBox>
```

[image: Rendering]

Comment: Unfortunately this means you have to explicitly tell each binding which template to use. This is annoying because in my case I want to bind to the same interface property, but have the underlying object change at runtime. I don't want to explicitly tell the binding to implement only one data template, because I want it to change that data template at runtime depending on the underlying object backing that property.

Answer (score 8):

The answer suggested by dummyboy is the best answer (it should be voted to the top imo). It does have an issue that the designer doesn't like it (gives an error "Object null cannot be used as an accessor parameter for a PropertyPath) but there is a good workaround. The workaround is to define the item in a datatemplate and then set the template to a label or other content control. As an example, I was trying to add an Image like this

```
<Image Width="120" Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Path=(starbug:IPhotoItem.PhotoSmall)}" Name="mainImage"></Image>
```

But it kept giving me the same error. The solution was to create a label and use a data template to show my content

```
<Label Content="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MouseDoubleClick="Label_MouseDoubleClick">
    <Label.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=(starbug:IPhotoItem.PhotoSmall)}" Width="120" Height="120" Stretch="Uniform" ></Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Label.ContentTemplate>
</Label>
```

This has its downsides but it seems to work pretty well for me.

Answer (score 5):

Note: You can use more complex multi-part paths like this too if the interface property is inside a path:

```
 <TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="Packages[0].(myNamespace:IShippingPackage.ShippingMethod).CarrierServiceCode"/>
    </TextBlock.Text>
 </TextBlock>
```

Or directly with the `Binding` directive.

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Packages[0].(myNamespace:IShippingPackage.ShippingMethod).CarrierServiceCode}"/>
```

Or when using multiple properties of an interface you can redefine the DataContext locally to make the code more readable.

```
 <StackPanel DataContext={Binding Path=Packages[0].(myNamespace:IShippingPackage.ShippingMethod)}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CarrierName}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CarrierServiceCode}"/>
  </StackPanel>
```

Tip: Watch out for accidentally ending up with `)}`at the end of a Path expression. Stupid copy/paste error I keep making.

`Path="(myNameSpace:IShippingPackage.ShippingMethod)}"`

---

#### Make sure to use `Path=`

Discovered that if I don't explicitly use `Path=` then it may not be able to parse the binding.
Typically I will just write something like this:

```
Text="{Binding FirstName}"
```

instead of

```
Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"
```

But with the more complex interface binding I found that `Path=` was needed to avoid this exception:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary.get_Item(Object key)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary.get_Item(Object key)
   at System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager.RemoveListener(INotifyPropertyChanged source, String propertyName, IWeakEventListener listener, EventHandler`1 handler)
   at System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager.RemoveHandler(INotifyPropertyChanged source, EventHandler`1 handler, String propertyName)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.ReplaceItem(Int32 k, Object newO, Object parent)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(Int32 k, ICollectionView collectionView, Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
```

i.e. don't do this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Packages[0].(myNamespace:IShippingPackage.ShippingMethod).CarrierServiceCode}"/>
```