# Using an Abstract Class as DataType in DataTemplates

Tags: c#, wpf, abstract-class, datatemplate

I have stumpled upon other StackOverflow questions regarding abstract classes and DataTemplates in C#, but somehow I don't get it to work.

Code looks like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractParser() {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteParser() : AbstractParser { }
```

Now, I want to create a DataTemplate using the abstract class (for a `ListBox`, containing elements of `ConcreteParser`.
However, I don't get it to work in a `DataTemplate`. Based on other posts (e.g. [WPF databinding to interface and not actual object - casting possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327984/wpf-databinding-to-interface-and-not-actual-object-casting-possible) ), this should be possible:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AbstractParser}" />
```

To formulate a concrete question:

If I want to create a template for a `ListBox` containing objects of many different concrete classes, which are all derived from one common abstract base class, what is the best option to do it? The properties are all defined in the abstract base class.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is still relevant but i was just wondering the same thing .
and you can create a DataTemplate for Abstract types .

here is a tester iv'e create :

CS :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public Base Base
    {
        get { return new Child(); }
    }

    public List<Base> BaseCollection
    {
        get { return new List<Base> { new Child(), new Child(), new Child2(), new Child2() }; }
    }
}

public abstract class Base
{
    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return "I'm a Base class"; }         
    }        
}

public class Child : Base
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "I'm A child"; }
    }
}

public class Child2 : Base
{

}
```

XAML :

```
 <Window>
    <Window.Resources>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Base}">
           <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="24" Text="{Binding Name}" />
       </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition />
           <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Base}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="30" Width="100" />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding BaseCollection}" Grid.Row="2"/>

    </Grid>
 </Window>
```

Comment: Was this tested? I've implemented the same pattern in my project but it doesn't seem to be finding the XAML for the child classes.

Comment: did it print "I'm a Base class" ?

Comment: Sorry, it turns out I was implemented a slightly different pattern and I got it working now. I think it actually was finding the XAML and it just didn't look the way I expected at first.