# WPF: BindingExpression returns null, although source property has an value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I am experiencing a very strange behavior with an ItemsControl's ItemTemplate. Some of the BindingExperssions return null, although the DataContext.

Here is the XAML in question:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Index}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="RowsControl">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:IndexCell}">
                            <Border Style="{StaticResource CellBorderStyle}"
                                    Background="{Binding BackgroundColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}"
                                    ToolTip="{Binding Path=ToolTip}">

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content}" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Path=HorizontalTextAlignment}"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

So, for example, I can see that visually the Content property from the DataContext is retrieved. The values I expect are indeed shown on the screen.However, HorizontalTextAlignment throws an error in the Output window in Visual Studio:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='<null>' BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalTextAlignment; DataItem='IndexCell' (HashCode=40508359); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')
```

The property in the DataContext object has the right type (System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment) and a value (I set one by default and this is an enum, so there is "no chance" to be null).

I also did one more test with an IValueConverter. When Path is specified in the Binding, the converter receives a null, indeed. When there is no path, it receives the whole object and I debugged it and it has value for the property.  It feels as if there is some bug in WPF, but I really hope that I am wrong.

Has anyone an idea why and how is this happening? Maybe how I can remedy this?

EDIT (as requested):
Here is the interface of the DataContext object

```
public interface ICell
{
    string Content { get; set; }
    Color TextColor { get; set; }
    Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    double FontSize { get; set; }
    FontWeight FontWeight { get; set; }
    TextWrapping TextWrapping { get; set; }
    HorizontalAlignment HorizontalTextAlignment { get; set; }
    VerticalAlignment VerticalTextAlignment { get; set; }
    string ToolTip { get; set; }
}
```

And ItemsSource property from the ViewModel:

```
private IReadOnlyList<ICell> _index;
    public IReadOnlyList<ICell> Index
    {
        get { return _index; }
        private set
        {
            if (_index == value)
                return;
            _index = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

EDIT2:
Here is the code of BasicCell

```
public abstract class BasicCell : BasicProxyElement, ICell
{

    [StyleProperty]
    public Color BackgroundColor
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetProperty<Color>("BackgroundColor", Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == BackgroundColor)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (this.TrySetProperty("BackgroundColor", value))
            {
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    [StyleProperty]
    public string Content
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetProperty<string>("Content", "");
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == Content)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (this.TrySetProperty("Content", value))
            {
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    [StyleProperty]
    public double FontSize
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetProperty<double>("FontSize", 11d);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == FontSize)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (this.TrySetProperty("FontSize", value))
            {
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    [StyleProperty]
    public FontWeight FontWeight
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetProperty<FontWeight>("FontWeight", FontWeights.Normal);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == FontWeight)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (this.TrySetProperty("FontWeight", value))
            {
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    [StyleProperty]
    public HorizontalAlignment HorizontalTextAlignment
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetProperty<HorizontalAlignment>("HorizontalTextAlignment", HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == HorizontalTextAlignment)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (this.TrySetProperty("HorizontalTextAlignment", value))
            {
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    [StyleProperty]
    public Color TextColor
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetProperty<Color>("TextColor", Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == TextColor)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (this.TrySetProperty("TextColor", value))
            {
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    [StyleProperty]
    public TextWrapping TextWrapping
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetProperty<TextWrapping>("TextWrapping", TextWrapping.Wrap);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == TextWrapping)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (this.TrySetProperty("TextWrapping", value))
            {
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    [StyleProperty]
    public string ToolTip
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetProperty<string>("ToolTip", null);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == ToolTip)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (this.TrySetProperty("ToolTip", value))
            {
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    [StyleProperty]
    public VerticalAlignment VerticalTextAlignment
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetProperty<VerticalAlignment>("VerticalTextAlignment", VerticalAlignment.Center);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == VerticalTextAlignment)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (this.TrySetProperty("VerticalTextAlignment", value))
            {
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public BasicCell(IGraphElement dataElement, IProxyGraph graph, string visualTarget) : base(dataElement, graph, visualTarget)
    {
    }
}
```

and of IndexCell:

```
public class IndexCell : BasicCell
{
    private static readonly IProxyElementFactory _factory = new DelegateProxyElementFactory("IndexCell",
        (graphElement, controller, visualTarget) => new IndexCell(graphElement, controller, visualTarget));

    public static IProxyElementFactory Factory
    {
        get { return _factory; }
    }

    private static readonly IStyleProvider _styleProvider = new ReflectionDefaultStyleProvider<IndexCell>();

    public static IStyleProvider StyleProvider
    {
        get { return _styleProvider; }
    }

    public IndexCell(IGraphElement dataElement, IProxyGraph graph, string visualTarget) : base(dataElement, graph, visualTarget)
    {
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please include the relevant code in the back-end

Comment: Seems to work fine. How are you constructing the collection?

Comment: Maybe your problem appears because you're doing a binding to interface? Take a look at this question, it may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327984/wpf-databinding-to-interface-and-not-actual-object-casting-possible

Comment: can you give the implementation of IndexCell? cause i created my own class and it worked fine.

Comment: Is IndexCell is implementing ICell?

Comment: @Kylo Ren, IndexCell inherits from BasicCell which implements ICell. BasicCell is an abstract class and also I have the properties from ICell implemented there

I think lena's direction might be the answer to the problem. I need to check it out.

Comment: @user1509777 can you give me other classes you talking about? just paste them also in the question..

Comment: @user1509777 dude it's all over the same again. you left the BasicProxyElement class. It's needed also. and if BasicProxyElement is derived from other classes please give them also.

Comment: @user1509777 or just to make it short give me the GetProperty() method definition . TrySetProperty() also.

Comment: also I've updated the answer. please see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can create your exception was like this

```
public interface ICell
{
    string Content { get; set; }
    Color TextColor { get; set; }
    Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    double FontSize { get; set; }
    FontWeight FontWeight { get; set; }
    TextWrapping TextWrapping { get; set; }
    HorizontalAlignment? HorizontalTextAlignment { get; set; }
    VerticalAlignment VerticalTextAlignment { get; set; }
    string ToolTip { get; set; }
}

public class IndexCell : ICell
{
   public string Content { get; set; }
   public Color TextColor { get; set; }
   public Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }
   public double FontSize { get; set; }
   public FontWeight FontWeight { get; set; }
   public TextWrapping TextWrapping { get; set; }
   public HorizontalAlignment? HorizontalTextAlignment { get; set; }
   public VerticalAlignment VerticalTextAlignment { get; set; }
   public string ToolTip { get; set; }
}
```

**So make sure that of the type you are using in IndexCell.** Somehow a type can contain null is reaching to binding.

My exception:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='<null>' BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalTextAlignment; DataItem='IndexCell' (HashCode=55786324); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')
```

**Look the enum property can return other values than specified in the enum.** for example try to cast any integer value to any enum.

```
 public HorizontalAlignment HorizontalTextAlignment
    {
        get
        {
            return (HorizontalAlignment)100;
        }            
    }
```

This will work fine and you will get a binding error at runtime(same as yours). I dont't know your class hierarchy so can't say for sure. But you are playing in generics here in **GetProperty(...)** method so that could return null. The only way you can know for sure is by debugging that how's it's coming as **< null>**.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but the your code does not reflect the one I have.