# WPF databinding to interface cannot find property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am working from the solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327984/wpf-databinding-to-interface-and-not-actual-object-casting-possible), which has worked well for me until this point.  I'm now trying to perform datatrigger binding to an interface property via the following XAML:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(selection:IChartDefinitionViewModel.SelectedItem).HasErrors}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(selection:IChartDefinitionViewModel.SelectedItem).HasErrors}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

When I enter this code I get a warning "The member 'SelectedItem' is not recognized or is not accessible", and I get a similar exception when I try to run.  Only thing is, there *is* a member SelectedItem defined on the interface, and I can even navigate to it from the XAML:

```
public interface IChartDefinitionViewModel : IReactiveSelector<SomeClass>, IMayHaveErrors
{
     // stuff
}

public interface IReactiveSelector<T> : // more stuff  
{
    T SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone advise why this is happening and what I can do for a workaround? I'd like to manage this based on the interface definition or using a datatemplate for my IChartDefinitionViewModel implementation, if possible.

**Update:**
This also does not work, but for a different reason - when I attempt to bind to the object directly, the background doesn't change despite the fact that HasErrors toggles from true to false.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.HasErrors}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.HasErrors}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Data binding works against the data context, not unimplemented interfaces. If you set the data context of the Window or grid to *any* object, you can bind to any property by name as long as the object has that property. There is no need for interfaces

Comment: Understood - unfortunately the binding still doesn't seem to work when I bind to the object directly (see update).

Comment: Your edit works for me as long as all the pieces are in place however, Is it possible your `DataContext`s are mixed up. Does each row really have a `SelectedItem` property?`

Comment: @JamesDurda, yes, you are correct.  If I specify {Binding Path=HasErrors} I get a warning that the property can't be resolved, but the program executes without issue.  Good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to have been two issues with my original post.  The first is that there was a datacontext issue - thanks to James Durda for pointing this out.  The row context is of type ChartDefinitionViewModel, so this code works as desired:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(selection:ChartDefinitionViewModel.HasErrors)}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(selection:ChartDefinitionViewModel.HasErrors)}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Interestingly, however, binding to the HasErrors property on the IChartDefinitionViewModel interface results in a thrown exception stating that the property path is invalid, which brings me back again to my original inquiry:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(selection:IChartDefinitionViewModel.HasErrors)}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(selection:IChartDefinitionViewModel.HasErrors)}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Things, however, begin to work as expected when I bind to the interface on which the HasErrors property is directly defined.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(interfaces:IMayHaveErrors.HasErrors)}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(interfaces:IMayHaveErrors.HasErrors)}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

I'm not sure if this is an isolated case, but it appears that WPF binding can't locate properties defined upwards in the interface inheritance hierarchy, at least in this instance.