# Bind WPF Label to 3rd party injected Interface

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have this interface which I get from 3rd party library in which I **cannot** create a new class of it.

Which means i **cannot** do these `IMeetingDetails meeting = new MeetingDetails(..)` because `MeetingDetails` is not exposed to my from that 3rd party library

```
 public interface IMeetingDetails
 {
    .....
    string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
 }
```

In my view model, I created a new instance

```
    IMeetingDetails _meetingDetails;
    public IMeetingDetails MeetingDetails
    {
        get { return _meetingDetails; }
        set
        {
            _meetingDetails = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

after the data is inject i do see the value as i expect
and when I'm trying to bind I'm getting an error

> BindingExpression path error: 'CustomerName' property not found on 'object' ''MeetingDetails' (HashCode=13209970)'. BindingExpression:Path=MeetingDetails.CustomerName; DataItem='SuggestionViewModel' (HashCode=8963855); target element is 'Label' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')

**Edit** autocomplete do work to this property and pressing

I tried the following, which non has worked

```
  <Label  Content="{Prototypes:IMeetingDetails.CustomerName}"  />

  <Label  Content="{Binding Path=(Prototypes:IMeetingDetails.CustomerName), Mode=OneWay}"/>

  <Label   Content="{Binding MeetingDetails.CustomerAddress }"  />
```

When I created a `string` named `CustomerAddress`, pass the data from the interface and bind to it. these is a solution that i dont want to go with because i have a lot of variable in that interface

Comment: Did existing threads help you, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327984/wpf-databinding-to-interface-and-not-actual-object-casting-possible) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578799/wpf-databinding-to-interface-cannot-find-property)?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski no, the first example you gave(and the 2nd) are the same(i think) as my 2nd attempt

Comment: With regards to interfaces, unless you are using _DataTemplates_ (as per the links) it should not matter what type the object is but only if the `property is public` _irrespective of whether you have access to the concrete type or not_.  I use interfaces all the time in my MVVM in order to promote decoupling, keeping my concretes `internal` in a _different assembly_ (I am essentially doing what the 3rd party is doing). I suspect you are using `DataTemplates` or `DataTrigger`s in which case Pavel is correct

Comment: Please post the XAML that is containing the `<Label>`s. What is setting up the data context?  i.e. Container? DataTemplate? control? Window?

Comment: @MickyD my label does `DataTemplates` or `DataTriggers` as I showed my label as it is at my code

Comment: @MickyD the DataContext is set at the **Window** Xaml with `<Window.DataContext>
        ....
    </Window.DataContext>`

Comment: @MickyD updated the question with better error reponse

Comment: Thanks for the update.  It changes things a bit because the error is saying you are attempting to bind to a non-existent property `CustomerName` on object `MeetingDetails`. Are you sure the 3rd party lib defines this property?

Comment: @MickyD, as i wrote the autocomplete for these property work well and pressing F12, do send me to that property.**Edit** this error happens for _every_ property in that class