# WPF: How to bind to interface that inherits from another interface?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, interface

I have an interfaces:

```
public interface IDocument : IEntity
{
    string FileName { get; set; }
    ...
}

public interface IEntity : IComparable
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I'd like to bind as following:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedEventPhotoList}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"                  
            Name="SelectedListView">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="3"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(documents:IDocument.FileName)}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(documents:IDocument.Id)}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The SelectedEventPhotoList is placed to view model as following:

```
public List<IDocument> SelectedEventPhotoList
{
    get { return _selectedEventPhotoList; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, _selectedEventPhotoList))
            return;

        _selectedEventPhotoList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedEventPhotoList);
    }
}
```

The first binding to FileName works fine, but the second one doesn't.

How to make it work?

Comment: @Clemens Aren't these [bindings to explicit interface implementations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1827579/5246145)?

Comment: I've updated the original post. Please, take a look.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand without the declaration of the class that implements IDocument. It is unclear why there should be any need for this special path syntax without the extra info that this class explicitly implements the interfaces. It would be great if you'd edit your question and add (the relevant parts) of that declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `IEntity.Id` is an explicitly implemented property you should replace `IDocument` with `IEntity` in your binding path:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(documents:IEntity.Id)}"/>
```

If not you should be able to bind to it using the common binding syntax:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
```