# How to trigger a method in a ViewModel from a WPF Ribbon button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ribbon, ribbon-control

I'm fairly inexperienced with WPF, Ribbon menus and C#, as well as the MVVM pattern. So please excuse any stupidity.

My problem is that I have a WPF app thai I am attempting to have a MainView which contains the ribbon component as well as a ContentControl displaying a current view.
How do I trigger a method in the current view from the MainView ribbon? It does seem to have some awareness of the view as it is getting the "Name" paramter from it, but throws an error if I attempt to bind to anything else (as that thing isn't in the interface I used to create the list of views).

Here is the code that I hope is enough to give a sense of my issue.

MainWindowView.xaml

```
<RibbonWindow x:Class="LIA.MainWindowView"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"              
              xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
              xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
              mc:Ignorable="d"              
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LIA" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainWindowViewModel}"
              Title="LIA"
              Width="Auto" Height="480">

    <RibbonWindow.Resources>
        <!-- views and models for the app -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SampleViewModel}">
            <local:SampleView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </RibbonWindow.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon" Title="Ribbon Title" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=ActualWidth}">
            <Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
                <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images/smallicon.png" />
            </Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
            <Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
                <RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
                    <RibbonButton x:Name="QATButton1"
                                  SmallImageSource="Images/SmallIcon.png" />
                    <RibbonButton x:Name="QATButton2"
                                  SmallImageSource="Images/SmallIcon.png" />
                </RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
            </Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
            <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
                <RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="Images\SmallIcon.png">
                    <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Hello _Ribbon"
                                               Width="Auto"
                                               x:Name="MenuItem1"
                                               ImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png" />
                </RibbonApplicationMenu>
            </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
                        <RibbonTab x:Name="SampleTab"
                       Header="Aname">
                            <RibbonGroup x:Name="SampleTabGroup1"
                             Header="A header">
                                <RibbonButton x:Name="aLargeButton"
                                              
                                  LargeImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png"
                                  Label="Button5"
                                  />
                            </RibbonGroup>
                        </RibbonTab>
                    
            <RibbonTab x:Name="tab"
                       Header="Sample Tab">
                <RibbonGroup x:Name="Group1"
                             Header="">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}">                        
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <RibbonButton
                                    x:Name="Button1"                                    
                                  LargeImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png"
                                  Label="{Binding Name}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                    
                </RibbonGroup>
            </RibbonTab>
                        
        </Ribbon>

        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" Grid.Row="1" />

    </Grid>

</RibbonWindow>
```

MainWIndowView.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;

namespace LIA
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindowView : RibbonWindow
    {
        public MainWindowView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }

    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace LIA
{
    class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        #region MainWindowViewModel Fields

        private ICommand _changePageCommand;
        private IPageViewModel _currentPageViewModel;
        private List<IPageViewModel> _pageViewModels;

        #endregion MainWindowViewModel Fields

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            //Add pages
            PageViewModels.Add(new SampleViewModel());
            CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels[0];
        }

        #region MainWindowViewModel Properties

        public List<IPageViewModel> PageViewModels
        {
            get
            {
                if (_pageViewModels == null)
                    _pageViewModels = new List<IPageViewModel>();

                return _pageViewModels;
            }
        }

        public IPageViewModel CurrentPageViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentPageViewModel;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_currentPageViewModel != value)
                {
                    _currentPageViewModel = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPageViewModel");
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion MainWindowViewModel Properties

        #region MainWindowViewModel Commands

        public ICommand ChangePageCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_changePageCommand == null)
                {
                    _changePageCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        p => ChangeViewModel((IPageViewModel)p),
                        p => p is IPageViewModel
                        );
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("page change command");
                return _changePageCommand;
            }
        }



        #endregion MainWindowViewModel Commands


        #region MaiWindowViewModel Methods

        private void ChangeViewModel(IPageViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (!PageViewModels.Contains(viewModel))
            {
                PageViewModels.Add(viewModel);

                CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels.FirstOrDefault(vm => vm == viewModel);
            }
        }

        #endregion MaiWindowViewModel Methods
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace LIA
{
    public interface IPageViewModel
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }
}
```

SampleViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Input;
using ZXing;
using ZXing.Datamatrix;

namespace LIA
{
    class SampleViewModel : ObservableObject, IPageViewModel
    {
        #region SampleViewModel Fields

        private ICommand _generateLabel;

        #endregion SampleViewModel Fields

        public SampleViewModel()
        {
            
        }


        #region SampleViewModel Properties

        public string Name
        {
            get { return "Sample"; }
        }

        #endregion SampleViewModel Properties

        #region SampleViewModel Commands

        public ICommand GenerateLabelCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_generateLabel == null)
                {
                    _generateLabel = new RelayCommand(
                        param => GenerateLabel(),                        
                        );
                }
                return _generateLabel;
            }
        }

        #endregion SampleViewModel Commands

        #region SampleViewModel Methods

        private void GenerateLabel()
        {
            //do the stuff I need to generate a label
        }

        #endregion SampleViewModel Methods
    }
}
```

I haven't included the SampleView.xaml or SampleView.xaml.cs as that seems to be working ok and I can trigger the method when the button is on that view.

and heres the output:
[Menus with button showing correct name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHWRn.png)

Been going crazy looking for solutions on this, which probably means there's a fundamental concept here I don't get yet.

Comment: Please check this guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
It's way easier for people if you provide enough code, so others can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly from your code: in your `RibbonGroup` named `Group1`, you want to have a `Button` for each item in `PageViewModels`, which will execute some code from that `IPageViewModel` item when clicked, correct?

In your example above, adding `Command="{Binding GenerateLabelCommand}"` to `Button1` should link it to the command in `SampleViewModel`. It shouldn't matter that the collection it's a part of is defined as a `List<IPageViewModel>`. If that doesn't work, more debugging details are needed.

That said, the above will *only* work for `SampleViewModel`, unless every `IPageViewModel` has a member named `GenerateLabelCommand`. If you want this to work for all `IPageViewModel` implementations, you should add an `ICommand` member to the interface and then bind explicitly to the interface implementation as explained in this question:
[WPF databinding to interface and not actual object - casting possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327984/wpf-databinding-to-interface-and-not-actual-object-casting-possible)

Comment: Perfect interpretation of my problem. Unfortunately the button shows as inactive when I do that (and VS gets upset about it not being in the interface). Per @Dominik's suggestion I'll try to copy the code to a new project to make a minimum working example and update the question accordingly when I have.

Comment: @Hulikoi Actually, if the `Button` shows as disabled, that probably means the `Command` binding worked. `Button`'s are automatically disabled when the assigned `ICommand` reports that it is not able to be executed. I'd check your `RelayCommand` implementation and make sure that `CanExecute` is returning `true` and `CanExecuteChanged` is being raised when needed.

Comment: quite right. 
I used a rutorial for the RelayCommand and to test I changed
``` 
public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }```

to
```
 public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true; //_canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }
```

and that method is now being called.
Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`? I don't have any rep to comment sorry.

Comment: I have not, could you explain that and how I might implement it in my code please?